# Accommodating The On Screen Keyboard in Xamarin Forms makes half the root page blank

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I implement this I have an issue on Android, if I am on a second screen in the stack and then press back to the previous page then a frame is left on the screen blocking half the root page. In the post's comments 2 solution are suggested

1. Update its screen size every time a page reloads.
2. Or, tap into the back button and cause it to close the keyboard first, then move back.

I have not been able to fix the issue with any of those, maybe I am implementing it wrong.

More info about the escenario here

https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Drop the use of the Workaround and the SetSoftInputMode and replace it with this, after your LoadApplication(new App());

```
App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Then set this workaround, because it screws up your StatusBar

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
            var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(0, 0, 0, 255)); // Change to your desired color
        }
```